# How to add Javascript Library for use in CouchDB views

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

**Disclaimer**: I am reviewing CouchDB for a new project, so I am not too familiar with its inner workings yet.

How can I introduce a Javascript Library into CouchDB so that I can use it in my MapReduce views?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I DRY up my CouchDB views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197449/how-do-i-dry-up-my-couchdb-views)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the answers (all of them) of this question they describe a range of possible solutions:

[How do I DRY up my CouchDB views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197449/how-do-i-dry-up-my-couchdb-views)